# Bold font shortcut in WordPress editor in Mac OS X? (The equivalent to Ctrl+b in Windows)

Tags: macos, fonts, shortcuts, wordpress

I've recently acquired a MacBook Air and I'm getting used to **Mac OS X shortcuts**. One that I can't find, though, is the change to **bold a piece of text** previously selected in the WordPress editor.

I do this with a simple Ctrl+b after selecting the text in Windows, but the expected Command+b in Mac OS X **does not work** (in WordPress at least. It seems it works in other editors online and offline). Is there a shortcut for it... and for *italics*?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl+B on the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the web interface (couldn't find "WordPress editor" software), it's `Ctrl-B` or `Alt-Shift-B`, as written in the *tooltip*. Similar with *I* for *italic*

Comment: Nowadays there is a WordPress Desktop app for Mac. https://apps.wordpress.com/desktop/